# Accept incoming connection on one port, inspect data, and pass to a process on another prot

Tags: ruby, minecraft

I am trying to create a minecraft server controller in Ruby. I have many basics done and have a decent understanding of programming in Ruby.

My end goal, besides the site to control everything, is to have Minecraft on one port, M, and another process on a different port ,P. I want users to connect to the port P and my process will inspect their traffic and chat logs before passing to Minecraft on port M. The goal is so that I can allow or deny individual op requests per player.

If this is possible or if I am approaching this wrong any help or direction is appreciated.

One concern of course is if this will slow gameplay making the game unplayable.

Comment: Not ruby but python: Guess http://mitmproxy.org/ could do that. Has scripting interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your goal is better accomplished with a Bukkit plugin, you can still do it with a proxy. You'll need to make your proxy understand the [Minecraft protocol](http://google.com), as well as setting your server to offline mode and making your proxy handle player authentication. You shouldn't see too much of a performance hit.

However, I suggest using [SMProxy](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/SMProxy) to achieve your goal. It's not Ruby (it's C#), but it's a very featureful and cross-platform Minecraft proxy with good plugin support for your needs. It's also updated pretty frequently, so you can keep on top of new versions of Minecraft without too much difficulty (this is the hardest part, reverse engineering Minecraft is no small task).